# Caching for frequently changing queries

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

We have a web application which listens to web service calls, constructs queries, pulls the data from database and sends the results back to the client. Since we are experiencing some performance issues, we want to cache the data on server side. The queries are complex which involve multiple joins. The database is updated through another application which is outside of the web app. I don't think we ca use EHCache as the database is not updated through the same application and the query parameters are changing frequently. What Caching strategies can we adapt here to improve the performance?
Note: The queries are optimized for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think we ca use EHCache as the database is not updated through the same application

If you don't go through Hibernate's API, Hibernate won't be able to *invalidate* the relevant second level cache regions when required. But you could do it yourself (see the various `evictXxx` methods on the `SessionFactory`). Depending on the frequency of updates, you might still get benefits.

Also note that EHCache is just one second level cache implementation amongst others (whether you're using EHCache or not is not relevant, it's using the 2nd level cache that is relevant to the question).

> (...) and the query parameters are changing frequently.

That's more annoying. Using the query cache works well for frequently executed queries (including the parameters). If re-executing a given query (including the parameters) is an unlikely event, you won't get much benefits from the query cache.

In that case, I would maybe try to use `Query#iterate()` instead of `Query#list()`. While the later returns the query results as `List`, with the former:

> Entities returned as results are initialized on demand. **The first SQL query returns identifiers only**.

This might give better performances **IF** the entities corresponding to the IDs are in the 2nd level cache. If they aren't, it won't perform better.

> What Caching strategies can we adapt here to improve the performance?

I don't have any better suggestion than the above one. Caching works when a cache hit is a likely event.

> Note: The queries are optimized for better performance.

Hmm... what do you mean? :)